# ¿Alguna manera de desatar solamente el último evento keyup en un input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando la manera de hacer un *login* con *ajax*. Por ahora estoy haciendo unas pruebas y quiero que al momento que dejen de escribir en el *input*, se desate la una función `validateUser` que es un simple *alert*.

El problema radica que si presiona 5 veces una tecla, el evento se desata 5 veces y eso no es práctico. ¿Mejor me decanto por "onblur" o conocen alguna otra manera?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
     $('#user').on('keyup', function(){
        setTimeout(validateUser, 1000);
     });
    });
    function validateUser () {
     var reset;
     alert('HOLa');
     clearTimeout(reset);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Ej. fernando.alvaradoLI" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes continuar con la línea de diseño que ya traes, simplemente almacenar el *timer* en una variable y desactivar el timer anterior cada vez que se presiona una tecla, para activarlo de nuevo.

Con eso, evitas que se dispare varias veces, hasta que ha pasado el tiempo del *timer* sin que el usuario escriba algo nuevo para lanzar la validación.

```js
    var validateUserTimer;

    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $('#user').on('keyup', function(){
            clearTimeout(validateUserTimer);
            validateUserTimer = setTimeout(validateUser, 500);
        });
    });

    function validateUser () {
        var reset;
        alert('HOLa');
        clearTimeout(reset);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Ej. juan" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que las preguntas del tipo "opinion" no están permitidas o bien vistas.

Te explico tu problema: el ordenador no puede saber cuando vas a acabar de escribir una palabra. Dicho con otras palabras: el ordenador no puede saber cuando tras pulsar en una letra, esa letra corresponde a la última letra de una palabra y por lo tanto has acabado de escribir esa palabra.

Esto quiere decir que lo que te pasa es totalmente normal. El evento que has decidido ejecutar, lo esta haciendo en cada pulsación de teclado (independientemente de que hayas utilizado un evento keypress, keyup, keydown,...).

Lo que deberías hacer es precisamente lo que tu mismo has propuesto. Utilizar algún tipo de evento que sea compatible con lo que quieres: por ejemplo el evento "blur" creo que sí que cubriría más o menos bien tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, el problema está que el timeout al retrasar el llamado de la función puede almacenar cuantas veces quiera el "keyup" de la tecla, o sea, en ese segundo que estas llamando si aprietas 10 veces la tecla antes del primer alert, 10 veces te aparecerá el mismo aviso. Para tus necesidades recomiendo el evento `onblur` que cubre al parecer mejor tus problema.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
     $('#user').blur(function(){
        setTimeout(validateUser, 1000);
     });
    });
    function validateUser () {
     var reset;
     alert('HOLa');
     clearTimeout(reset);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Ej. fernando.alvaradoLI" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Estaba bien lo que venías haciendo pero le hice algunas correcciones. Te dejé comentado cada línea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var time;
  var seValido = false;
  // evento del keyup
  $('#user').on('keyup', function() {
    // mientras no se haya validado
    if (!seValido) {
      // limpio el timeout cada vez que se ejecute el evento
      clearTimeout(time);
      // vuelvo a setear para resetear el tiempo
      time = setTimeout(validateUser, 2000);
    }
  });
  function validateUser() {
    // Acá hago la validación o petición
    console.log('Validación');
    // Seteo que ya se validó para que no vuelva a ejecutarse
    seValido = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Ej. fernando.alvaradoLI" >
```